# Signing jwt token with refresh token as payload

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, jwt

**How I understand jwt based authentication should work:**

1. Client sends log-in credentials to server.
2. Server verifies if credentials are correct and responds with a signed jwt token and a refresh token, while also storing the refresh token in database.
3. Client uses jwt token as a Authentication header in all requests.
4. When the jwt token has expired, server responds with `401 Unauthorized`.
5. Client sends a request to refresh the jwt token with the refresh token in the Authentication header.
6. Server check if the refresh token exists in database and that it has not expired. Then responds with a new jwt token
7. Client can continue requesting with the new token.

**How I want to implement it:**

If the desciption above is correct, is there anything wrong with putting the refresh token as payload for the signed jwt token?:

```
function signToken(id, role, refresh_token) {
    return jwt.sign(
        {
            _id: id,
            role: role,
            refresh_token: refresh_token
        },
        config.jwt.secret,
        {
            expiresIn: 60*60*24, // expires in 1 day
        }
    );
}
```

And in that way always sending both the refresh token and jwt token in every request? By doing this, the client would not have to send a seperate request with the refresh token to get a new jwt token:

1. *Same as above*
2. *Same as above*
3. *Same as above*
4. When the jwt token has expired, the server picks out the refresh token from the jwt token and checks if it exists in database and that it is not expired.
5. Server responds with the requesed resource + a new jwt token.
6. Client sees that there is a new token in the response and saves it for further requests.

Auth middleware would look something like this:

```
function authenticate (req, res, next) {

    // Token attached to request in previous middleware
    let token = req.token

    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, config.jwt.secret, {ignoreExpiration: true}, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: err.message });
        }
        //Expired token, try to refresh
        if(decoded.exp*1000 < Date.now()){
            User.findById(decoded._id, (err, user) => {
                if(err) {return res.send(err);}
                if(!user){
                    return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Token owner not found.' });
                }

                //if refresh token found, and not expired, refresh expiry time
                let isValidToken = _(user.refresh_tokens)
                                        .filter( (token) => {return token.expires>Date.now()} )
                                        .any({token: decoded.refresh_token});
                if(!isValidToken){
                    req.user = {role: 'Guest'};
                    return next();
                }

                let newToken = signToken(decoded._id, decoded.role, decoded.refresh_token);
                req.token = newToken;
                req.user = decoded;
                return next();
            })
        } else {
            // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
            req.user = decoded;
            return next();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Send the `refresh_token` as little as possible.
One of the mechanism `refresh_token` relies on is that it is transmitted only rarely (i.e. not with every request)

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer I hear what your saying, I just don't understand why. If you use HTTPS and store the jwt token securely on the client, my thinking is that it should be safe to send it in every request. If the security is compromised somehow, then they would be able to get the refresh token very soon anyway (considering its recomended to use a very short expiry time).

Comment: If HTTPS is secure, why would you need a `refresh_token` in the first place ;)
The issue here is that you want to give attackers as little opportunity as possible. If tokens are intercepted or otherwise retrieved, they will be only valid for a short amount of time. If a refresh token is intercepted, you have given away the keys and will only find out when that refresh token expires. It often does not for convenience reasons.

Comment: here's a good intro to when and how refresh tokens should be used
https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

Comment: The only benefit of the refresh token in my implementation would be to provide a way to blacklist them. By removing the refresh token from database, the jwt token would no longer be refreshed. But I guess I have a lot to learn, thanks for the link!